# web3.py function get_block tranactions is not in the current block

Tags: python, transactions, ethereum, blockchain, web3py

I want to synchronize all transactions with the database, so I use get_ Block method. The code is as follows：

```
    cur_block_num = web3.eth.get_block_number()
    if cur_block_num <= last_block_num:
        return
    res = web3.eth.get_block(cur_block_num, full_transactions=True)
    block_info = json.loads(web3.toJSON(res))
    block_info = convert_numeric_to_str(block_info)
    transactions = block_info.pop('transactions')
    db["block_info"].insert_one(block_info)
```

but When I get all the transactions in block 16498524, I eventually include the transactions in other blocks. Why is this, and sometimes it is normal? Is my method wrong? Have I got the transactions to be processed? Or is the node alchemy I use now returning the wrong value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain tips are unstable in Ethereum chains. Because you are dealing with the latest block, transactions may hop between different blocks as some blocks do not get included in the canonical blockchain.

You need to use a chain reorganisation-aware block reading to be able to read recent transactions and events. [Some example here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. Isn't the block already packed? Why would restructuring occur? I haven't seen any examples. Can you explain them to some websites in detail, or can I chat with you privately

Comment: Try here https://academy.moralis.io/blog/what-is-chain-reorganization - Sorry I do not have time for tutoring. If you have more questions you can ask them on sites like ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, thank you again, so if I want to achieve the effect of synchronization of all block databases, can I only synchronize safe blocks? Unsafe blocks may be restructured

Comment: I gave you a link to a full example how to solve this issue. You will figure it out yourself after studying the source code.